# Where can I find information on integrating Java applications into the Ubuntu application indicator menu?

Tags: java, ubuntu, indicator, ubuntu-unity

I have a Java application that essentially functions like an instant messaging type of program.  Until the recent "upgrades" to Ubuntu with the Unity interface I had a simple icon showing up in the system tray.  I realise there has been a lot of discussion regarding going back to the original purpose of this tray and don't desire to discuss that here.  Rather, I'm looking for a simple and concise tutorial or documentation on how to properly integrate my app into the messaging system.  I want new messages to pop-up notifications, and I've been able to do that through libnotify, however I don't know how to add the app itself as an entry under the messaging menu.  Any help pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated.  I need the app to continue working cross-platform.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to solve this is to use the Java DBUS library ( http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-java/ ) and learn about the Unity appindicator DBUS API. Then, write a special component for Unity and dynamically load this component if you are running Ubuntu.